# select onchange get option name attribute value

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a html page:

```js
function getName(val)
{
  alert(val.value);
  alert(val.getAttribute('name'));
}
```

```html
<select onchange="getName(this)">
  <option name="1" value="data1">Data 1</option>
  <option name="2" value="data2">Data 2</option>
  <option name="3" value="data3">Data 3</option>
</select>
```

I want that option `name` and `value` data. It returns `value` data as expected ,but it return `name` data as `null`.

What should I do?

Any help is appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here in the function `getName` the argument  `select` refers to the `select` element, but not the selected `option`. Use `selectedIndex` to get the selected `option` then use `getAttribute`

```js
function getName(select) {
  // You can get the value like you did 
  var value = select.value;
  console.log(value);

  // And here we get the name
  var selectedOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
  var name = selectedOption.getAttribute('name');
  console.log(name);
}
```

```html
<select onchange="getName(this)">
  <option name="1" value="data1">Data 1</option>
  <option name="2" value="data2">Data 2</option>
  <option name="3" value="data3">Data 3</option>
</select>
```

You could also do the following (which is more clear)

```
function getName(select) {
  var selectedOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
  var value = selectedOption.getAttribute('value');
  var name = selectedOption.getAttribute('name');
  console.log(value, name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getName()
{
       alert(event.target.value);
       alert(event.target.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute('name'));
}
```

```html
 <select onchange="getName()">
        <option name="1" value="data1">Data 1</option>
        <option name="2" value="data2">Data 2</option>
        <option name="3" value="data3">Data 3</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would also like to suggest a different answer that, I think, highlights better web programming practices.

In my opinion, you shouldn't use something like `onchange="getName(**this**)"` in your HTML. You should attach the function to the `select` element via Javascript.

For demonstration purpose, we will add an **id** to our `select` element so we can find it in the DOM quickly.

```
<select id="mySelect">
  <option name="1" value="data1">Data 1</option>
  <option name="2" value="data2">Data 2</option>
  <option name="3" value="data3">Data 3</option>
</select>
```

Next we write our Javascript

```
// When the page is loaded...
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  // Find your select...
  var mySelect = document.getElementById("mySelect");

  // Attach the function to the "onChange" event.
  mySelect.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
    // Retrieve the select element from the event.
    var select = event.target;
    var selectedOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
    var value = selectedOption.getAttribute('value');
    var name = selectedOption.getAttribute('name');
    console.log(value, name);
  });
});
```

It is a more structured and clean way of solving the problem.

Hope you learned something new!